# some logical error in taking up character in java

Tags: java, string-comparison

This is my code...

```
class info{
    public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException{
        char gen;

        while(true) {   //problem occurs with this while
            System.out.print("\nENTER YOUR GENDER (M/F) : ");
            gen=(char)System.in.read();

            if(gen=='M' || gen=='F' || gen=='m' || gen=='f'){
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nGENDER = "+gen);
    }
}
```

This is my output...

```
ENTER YOUR GENDER (M/F) : h

ENTER YOUR GENDER (M/F) :
ENTER YOUR GENDER (M/F) :
ENTER YOUR GENDER (M/F) : m

GENDER = m
```

Could someone please help me understand why it is asking for the gender so many times.

Comment: You can edit your question (link below your question) to add that code instead of posting it as a comment - it will look much better!

Comment: ok. thanx... actually i am new to this as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably workin' on Windows. When you give an answer and hit enter it adds two extra characters `'\r'` and `'\n'`. From `stdin` you receive only one character but those extra two remain in the buffer. When you give an incorrect answer you loop and automatically read from the buffer those two characters. They don't match the gender so the loop continues. The best solution would be to analyze strings instead of characters:

```
InputStreamReader converter = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(converter);
String s = in.readLine();
```

Remember to use `equals` method instead of `==` in string comparison.

Comment: thanx yob... in this i have to add some package also or not?

Comment: and can u explain me the reason why these 2 characters are added automatically?

Comment: Each character (even not printable) has it's own byte representation. Some of them (used often by people) have also their mnemonic representations. New line is e.g. `\n`, tab is `\t` etc. When an application reads your input and you hit enter it receives "text\n". In Windows before `\n` is added automatically `\r`. So you have: "text\r\n". When you read the message char after char you have to remember that those characters were also added as an input. When you typed "h" the real content in input buffer was "h\r\n". You read from the buffer char after char so after "h" you get `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: yob can u help with the code i have written above using break label?... details have been given there itself...

Answer (score 4):

You pressed return after pressing `h`; you won't *see* the `'h'` until you do so, but then you'll still see the return (and by the looks of it, that's coming out as two characters, possibly `'\r'` and `'\n'`) before you see the next character.

You may want to read a *line* of text at a time, instead of a single character - you'll only see the input when the user presses return anyway, and it means you don't need to worry about this particular aspect.

You could use `Scanner` for this, or a `BufferedReader` wrapping `System.in`.

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal: Use `new Scanner(System.in)` and then read lines from it.

Comment: okay... i got it thanx... actually i know the ways to input a string from the method nextLine() but not knowing any method which cud juz take up the character... can u help me in this matter???

Answer (score 0):

Use `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)`

Here is the working version of your code....

```
public class Info{


        public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException{

        char gen;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);          // Change made here

            while(true) {  

                System.out.print("\nENTER YOUR GENDER (M/F) : ");

                gen= scan.next().charAt(0);             // Change made here

                if(gen=='M' || gen=='F' || gen=='m' || gen=='f'){
                    break;
                }
                else{                                 // Change made here
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Your Option is not Available, pls try again");
                    continue;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("\nGENDER = "+gen);
        }
    }
```

Comment: sir one small doubt that why we pass System.in as arguments in Scanner constructor and why dont we leave it blank?

Comment: and i know the ways to input a string from the method nextLine() but not knowing any method which cud juz take up the character... can u help me in this matter too?